# Restrict lambda expression argument to the properties of a class

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a base class which needs to process the names of the properties of derived classes (explicit access). To do so, I created a method which takes a lambda expression as input:

```
private string GetMemberName(Expression<Func<object>> expression)
{
    //gets the property name (MemberExpression or UnaryExpression)
    //out of scope
    return propertyName;
}
```

This allows me to call the method like so:

```
derived.GetMemberName(() => derived.MyPropertyInt);
derived.GetMemberName(() => derived.MyPropertyStr);
```

The problem is that `object` is not restrictive at all. I can also call:

```
derived.GetMemberName(() => "something"); //does not "return" anything but compiles (out of scope)
derived.GetMemberName(() => anotherClass.RandomMember); //not derived from "base"
```

How can I restrict the `GetMemberName` method so that it can only accept as input the members of the classes which derive from my base class? Setting `GetMemberName(Expression<Func<MyBaseClass>> expression)` restricts access to an entire class. Setting `GetMemberName(Expression<Func<MyBaseClass, object>> expression)` restricts access to the current instance but still allows "random" objects to be passed.

EDIT:
The comment for `derived.GetMemberName(() => "something");` was in the context of returning the property name, not the "value" of the lambda expression. The `GetPropertyName` method does not return anything, due to the fact that I'm only analyzing `MemberExpression` or `UnaryExpression`.

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't. I would love to have this ability, but the only mechanism I have found is to perform checks in GetMemberName to ensure a property has been passed and to thrown an exception if something other than a property has been passed.

Comment: Could you not just have `GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)` and derived types would specify `T`

Comment: @user460667, checking if the input (name) is a valid property is a good idea. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I restrict the GetMemberName method so that it can accept only members of the classes which derive from my base class?

It's not clear what you mean by "accept" here, but if you're trying to restrict the set of valid lambda expressions to ones which uses members of your class, you can't. Lambda expressions and expression trees happen to be useful for getting this information, but that's not what they're designed for, so there are no specific features accommodating this. You'll always be able to use a lambda expression which doesn't just use a property.

The simplest approach is probably just to check this at execution time. You won't be able to stop people abusing your method at compile-time, but so long as it's simple to do the *right* thing, I wouldn't worry too much about callers doing the *wrong* thing - just make the error message really clear.

Comment: I was not clear enough regarding the string as lambda expression. My apologies. I edited the question.

Comment: @AndreiV: Okay - I'll get rid of that bit from my answer for clarity for future readers.

Comment: Since this is already eight years ago, is there some attribute which we can use nowadays with the current state of the roslyn compiler? I cannot find it but it might be possible?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen: I would hope folks would just use the `nameof` operator these days anyway.